# Next Business Date Column

Tags: sum, databricks

I have a dataset that looks like this.

[image: dataset sample]

Where `business_day` indicates whether the `transaction_created_date` is a business day or not. I'm trying to sum the `line_amount` so that values that occurred over the holiday or weekend gets added to the next business day to look something like this:

[image: output]

Essentially, if I can capture the next business day where `business_day = 0` then I can just do a sum over partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH
cte AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(business_day) OVER (ORDER BY transaction_created_date DESC) num
    FROM sourcetable
)
SELECT *, SUM(line_amount) OVER (PARTITION BY num) business_day_line_amount
FROM cte;
```